# In NestJS how can I associate a token with module registered using registerAsync?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm using NestJS `CacheModule` and register it using `registerAsync` in order to use `useFactory` and inject config module.

I want to provide a special token, because I intend to have multiple cache managers. Using `provide` is not supported with `registerAsync`. How can I achieve this?

Code example:

```js
import { CacheModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ENVALID } from 'nestjs-envalid';
import * as redisStore from 'cache-manager-redis-store';

export const CacheManager1 = CacheModule.registerAsync({
  provide: "CACHE_MANAGER_1", //this is not possible
  useFactory: async (env: EnvironmentConfig) => {
    return {
      ttl: env.MANAGER_ONE_TTL_SEC,
      store: redisStore,
      host: env.MANAGER_ONE_REDIS_HOST,
      port: env.MANAGER_ONE_REDIS_PORT,
      password: env.MANAGER_ONE_REDIS_PASSWORD,
      db: env.MANAGER_ONE_REDIS_DB,
    };
  },
  inject: [ENVALID],
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a very similar vein as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67632830/how-to-implement-multiple-jwt-strategies-using-multiple-secrets-in-nest-js/67641256#67641256) you can create a dedicated module for *this* CacheModule's options and export the `CACHE_MANAGER` under a new token. This would look something like

```js
@Module({
  imports: [CacheModule.registerAsync(asynCacheManagerOptions)],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'CustomCacheToken',
      useExisting: CACHE_MANAGER,
    }
  ],
  exports: ['CustomCacheToken'],
})
export class CustomCacheModule {}
```

And now *this* cache manager can be injected with `@Inject('CustomCacheToken')`

Comment: Can I register more than one Cache and have a different token name?

Comment: @iamshaojin you'll need to do that with multiple modules, but yes you can

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Would any other service using CACHE_MANAGER directly to access some cache overwrite the object using CustomCacheToken as a injection token ?

If yes then how can we use CACHE_MANAGER in a way that any N number of cache instances have totally separate cache manager and do not overwrite each other. There is no answer on internet for this.